# RCP's exec launcher can't find companion shared library on launch, but starts with click on org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm building an Eclipse RCP application against Eclipse 3.7.1 and Java 1.6.
I'm also using Tycho to build, and have set up my RCP according to the [Tycho tutorial from the EclipseCon 2011](http://eclipsecon.org/sessions/building-eclipse-plugins-and-rcp-applications-tycho), to which I've stuck slavishly, apart from project names.

The application builds fine up until I get to Step 5 (adding a p2 repo, then adding a `.product` file. Well, it still *builds* fine, and everything is where it should be, but I cannot start the RCP by clicking on the `.exe` file from the repository in the workspace.

All I get is the old dreaded "The [RCP] executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library" error popup.

First of all I thought I might have set up the CLASS PATH incorrectly, but when I open a console and type `javaw` or `java -version` anywhere, it all works.

Also, when I go to the `plugins`folder in the p2 repository for the RCP in the workspace, and double-click on `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar`, the RCP starts, albeit without the splash screen.

*This must surely mean my Java set up is correct, and it's not a class path problem?*

I'm not sure where this problem might lie (I have a plugin, a feature, a product, a repository, and a parent package with the main pom), so if you let me know your suspicions where the error might come from, I'll be more than happy to post respective `XML`, `build.properties`, screenshots and what have you. Unless this is a common error with a common solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Oh yea: Windows 7 (64-bit), JDK and JRE both 64-bit as well, Eclipse EE 3.7.1 (I chose that because it contains the most plugins I'll need later by default).

## UPDATE

I'm attaching my CLASS PATH Settings for reference.

**User variables**

- CLASS PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30;.;

**System variables**

- JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30
- Path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

## UPDATE 2

When I let Tycho create a ZIP file in the p2 repository, and copy that from the repo to another location, unzip it and run the .exe, the application starts without problems. So I guess this query is partially solved, but I'd still be interested to hear why I wouldn't be able to start the application from the repository...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I came across the same issue. I guess you could find the solution here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=176084

In short, the problem in my case was, that the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar must be unpacked in the plugins folder under the folder name: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502

... hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error `The [RCP] executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library` was because my path was too long.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I was facing from yesterday. Today, I have changed path of project(git clone) and build it and able to run RCP executable.

I think this issue was because of path too long.